# in my thesis, in auto generated table of contents, i don't want contents written as chapter in latex

Tags: table-of-contents, templates, thesis

[image: Table of contents of my thesis]

As you can see, in my auto generated table of contents, Contents is coming twice, one as Page heading (which I require it as it is), another as chapter name with page number (I don't want this) but I don't know how to remove it.
My Code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{Thesis}   
\newif\iftightnextchapter  
\tightnextchapterfalse
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\rightmargin}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.8in}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{cmr}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,lined,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\input{abstract.tex}
\singlespacing
\input{keywords.tex}
\newpage
\singlespacing
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\end{document}
```

Rest everything is coming perfectly in my thesis.

Comment: Ahh, the good old `Thesis` class...  Where did you get this from?

Comment: This is not the default behaviour. Something in `Thesis` is likely responsible.

Comment: Let me guess (as you can hear from other comments there is not definitive **Thesis** class, we need to know exactly which one you use), does `\tableofcontents*` help? Recompile twice. In addition it is probably a good idea to learn to use `\frontmatter `  and `\mainmatter ` instead of messing with page numbering manually

Answer (score 3):

The entry for the table of contents in the table of contents is indeed ridicoulous. You can easily remove it.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{Thesis} 
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand{\addtotoc}[1]{}
\tableofcontents}
\chapter{Wombat}
\end{document}
```

---

Note: By using sections you get the strange output. Using proper chapters would be the way to properly use any class that provides chapters.

---

This was tested with Release 1.4.3. of [the probable template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis), dated 2014-05-17.  With release of version 2.0 (2015-08-24), the table of contents is not visible in the toc by default. To toggle it *on*, you have to give the global option `toctotoc`.

Comment: Is `\addtotoc` a command provided by `Thesis`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, it is basically `addcontentsline...`, along with a `\refstepcounter{dummy}`. No joke.

Comment: Oh my.... I assume `\newcounter{dummy}` is issued by `Thesis` as well then?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, exactly above it.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40962074#40962074